# Will /blog/ at the start of the URL path for my WordPress articles help SEO?

Tags: seo, wordpress, url, url-rewriting, url-slug

I have a WordPress website for a business. And they have many pages, Custom Posts, etc. And they do have a Blog also.

At present their blog urls are like this:

```
Main page for blog: example.com/blog 

A blog post page: example.com/my-article-about-a-random-topic
```

My question is, if I change the permalink structure to follow the below mentioned pattern(prepending a `/blog/` in slug) for the individual blog posts:

```
example.com/blog/my-article-about-a-random-topic
```

Will it improve SEO? The website is actually live for sometime now and is having some traffic though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are going to change the already existing URL / permalink on an existing website, you can expect a dip in traffic after having to redirect it (301).

On the question whether you should do this change or not: that's entirely up to you. If you think that "blog" is meaningful for your users or will improve your SEO keyword matching, there won't be a good reason (except for the traffic dip) to state that you can't do it.

So, you can do it, but you would need to think if the permalink is adding value to your users and if it's worth the traffic dip. For Google, it won't matter if you have that slug there or not.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

While Google does recognize that /blog has a special meaning that signals a blog, semantically speaking adding /blog means nothing and adds no value to the URL.

If you were just starting out, I would say it was a flip of a coin whether you use /blog or not. Using /blog is not at all necessary. It would only be a personal preference.

Since your site is already established, I would advise not making the change. Making this change as @Siyah indicates would create a dip in your sites performance and would benefit from 301 redirects. I would add there is no gain for making the change.

I personally would leave things the way they are.

Comment: Thank you for the comments. Appreciate it.